# Where can I ask about the legality of printing the Nintendo logo (and trademarks) on unlicensed retro spare parts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about the legality of printing the [Nintendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo) logo (and trademarks) on unlicensed retro spare parts.

> If you search for "GBA lens" on [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=gba%20lens) you will find replica of the glass/ lens for the Game Boy Advance. The (original) "Game Boy Advance" logo is printed on them. I want to know if this is legal. I think the logo graphic is copyrighted by Nintendo. Also Game Boy is a registered trademark.
>
> Some manufacturers print the Nintendo logo and other's don't. So I am not sure. I've heard about "right to restore".

Which is the right site to ask this question on? [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), or elsewhere?

Comment: This question would almost certainly be off-topic on Arqade. See [this Meta discussion the community had on the subject](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3820/242480). Additionally, Arqade's "legal" tag's wiki says: *"USE WITH CAUTION. Questions asking if something is (il)legal are off topic here. Use this tag for questions concerning EULAs, Terms of Service, Licensing & Public Domain queries or otherwise related to the laws that protect games, their creators and their consumers."*

Comment: probably law.se is the place

Comment: Law seems the most fitting.

Answer (score 1):

This squarely fits within the scope of [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/). Be aware that they cannot give legal advice, so you should not ask whether or not it's legal for you to do X, but rather what the laws regarding X *are*.